# How to move the button to the west layout and move the shape

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I want to know how to move the button to the west layout and how to move the shape. i've tried to do it and all i get is an error.

```
public MyPanel(final Shapechange shapechange)
    {


        button = new JButton("oval");
        add(button);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            //Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                b = 1;
                shapechange.repaint();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.  See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

to add your button to the west border you need to use a `BorderLayout` in the parent component and add your button by using `add(button, BorderLayout.WEST)`

To move your shape you have to make sure that you are making some change to the `x` or `y` position of your shape. just calling the repaint method will not work if you do not change the `x` or `y` position of your shape .